# Forcing Eclipse to generate standard Unix makefiles

Tags: eclipse, makefile, cmake

I have an Eclipse project I've been working on for some time now, and I'd like to open source it. But to do that I'd like to have a clean Makefile like the majority of other open source programs. I understand I could make my own, but it would be better if Eclipse could manage it for me. Getting Eclipse to generate a CMake file would be even better, but I can settle for a plain makefile if that is easiest. So, how can I get Eclipse to do this? There are a few posts on the internet that suggest selecting "Managed make" when creating a project, but they were from a few years ago and are outdated. When I try to create a C project, there is the option to create a "Makefile project", but it creates the makefile in a folder called "Linux GCC" and makes everything cluttered. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've always used the autotools to generate Makefiles

Comment: Well after downgrading to Gandymede I was able to install autotools in Eclipse. But could you explain how to set everything up? Eclipse can get very confusing to me sometimes. I would put the explanation in an answer so I can mark it as right.

Comment: I am using CMake (no more automake hell for me ;-)) and I maintain my CMakeLists file myself. CMakeBuilder seems very outdated, as is the eclipse project generator from CMake itself. Maintaining CMakeLists is generally easy and CMake Editor plugin makes this even easier, but I would like to have a managed make for eclipse, so I am interested in answer too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just creating a CMake project by hand. CMake files are really not that hard to make, and it's a lot easier than trying to get Eclipse to do it for you. Plus, they're cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

I've been a *nix guy for 25+ years and am a big fan of make. However, making your Eclipse project dependent upon make is going to exclude the Mac and Windows community. Why don't you  just export the Eclipse project and open source it as an Eclipse project? Then users can can have it ready to extend if they choose. You didn't specify the language your project is written in, if it's Java (pretty common for Eclipse) why not create an ant build file for the project?

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Would a [**CMakeBuilder**](http://www.cmakebuilder.com/) eclipse plugin, associated with this [tutorial](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse) be a good fit for what you are trying to do?

The end result would be something like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [vtk.org](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/images/4/4f/Eclipse_Tutorial_1.png))</sub>

Comment: That plugin doesn't seem to be supported by Gandymede or Galileo. Gandymede spits out many typecast errors and Galileo can't even see it when add the update site.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been building your project using the Debug configuration the makefile Eclipse generates is stored in the Debug folder of your project (or the Release folder if you've built it using the release configuration).